# Performing complex conditional operation on numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

mat_a = np.random.random((5, 5))
mat_b = np.random.random((5, 5))
mat_c = np.random.random((5, 5))
```

Lets say for a specific grid cell, the values in the same position in the 3 arrays are as follows:
`mat_a, A = 0.3`
`mat_b, B = 0.2`
`mat_c, C = 0.1`

Here, we find the array with the least value, in this case it is C

1. We compute the amount of `C` that should be allocated to `B` as `0.1 * (0.2/ (0.2 + 0.3))` i.e. Value of cell in `C` multiplied by  the fraction of `B` with `total` being `A + B`. The newly computed value is stored in a `2D` array called `C_B`
2. Similarly, the amount of `C` that should be allocated to `A` is `0.1 * (0.3/(0.2 + 0.3))`. The newly computed value is stored in a `2D` array called `C_A`.
3. We repeat this process for cells where least value is in array `B`, storing the newly computed results in `2D` arrays `B_C` and `B_A` respectively.
4. We repeat this process for cells where least value is in array `A`, storing the newly computed results in `2D` arrays `A_C` and `A_B` respectively.

The only way I can think of doing this is using nested for loops, but that would be prohibitive for larger arrays and not very pythonic. Is there a fast and pythonic solution?

-- edit

`C_B` should contain 0 where `mat_c` does not contain smallest value

Comment: Does e.g., `C_B` just contain zeros at all positions where `mat_c` did not contain the smallest value?

Comment: What do you want the other cells to be? For instance, when c had the smallest number, do you want corresponding locations in `A_C`, `A_B`, `B_C` and `B_A` to be zeros? It might also help if you point to what you are finally trying to accomplish with these arrays.

Comment: @BrenBarn, thanks for the question. Yes, `C_B` should contain 0 where `mat_c` does not contain smallest value

Comment: thanks @VBB, edited question to respond to ur query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to calculate all values, replace unwanted ones with zeros.

```
mat_a = np.random.random((5, 5))
mat_b = np.random.random((5, 5))
mat_c = np.random.random((5, 5))
bigmat = np.stack((mat_a, mat_b, mat_c)) # this is a 3, 5, 5 array
minima = np.argmin(bigmat, axis=0) # contains a 5x5 array of 0,1,2 for a,b,c respectively
c_a = mat_c * mat_a / (mat_b + mat_c)
c_a[minima != 2] = 0
```

You can repeat this for the other 5 answer arrays. Or, you could also do:

```
c_a = np.zeros((5,5))
c_a[minima == 2] = (mat_c * mat_a / (mat_b + mat_c))[minima == 2]
```